# Data pattern SQL

Tags: sql

This I am sure is a fairly simple question. Clients are entering data into a column that looks like this 600/4768/4. I need to be able to remove the / once the data has been entered. How would I do this?

It is usually entered in this format as it is being referenced from another source in this pattern.

Comment: consider accepting answer that helps and resolve your issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it either in program before data is submitted, or in sql. Exactly how depends on what you're programming with, an what database you're using.

in MySql you can do this: replace('00/4768/4', '/', ''); Most any rdbms will have a similar function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

I usually find it's easier to do this kind of thing in the program than in sql though.

Answer (score 0):

USe REPLACE if you want to update in SQL
like

```
REPLACE(<column_Name>,'/',' ')
```

whole query will look like

```
Update <table_name>
set <column_Name> = REPLACE(<column_Name>,'/','')
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL SERVER you can try [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another
>   string value.

Usage:

```
SELECT REPLACE('abcdefghicde','cde','xxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **REPLACE** function in your SQL query:

```
replace( string1, string_to_replace, [ replacement_string ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select REPLACE('600/4768/4','/','')
```

While user enters the data take it and then replace the "/" and then store in the table

Answer (score 0):

While inserting client data in to column you can use the REPLACE function, I believe, you are using SQLServer. Below is the example how you can use replace.

```
REPLACE('600/4768/4','/','');
```